# Edit table in word docx using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, docx, python-docx

How can I edit an already existing table in a word document using Python.
Let's say inside my word document i have a table with only 2 rows and I want to add more rows in Python, how can i do this? I've tried with `docx` library but the best I can do with this is creating a table and saving it to a word document.

I want to edit an already existing table. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Code

You can do this in the docx library, by accessing `.tables` from a `Document`.

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('grid.docx')
doc.tables #a list of all tables in document
print("Retrieved value: " + doc.tables[0].cell(0, 0).text)
doc.tables[0].cell(0, 0).text = "new value"
doc.tables[0].add_row() #ADD ROW HERE
doc.save("grid2.docx")
```

## From

[image]

## To

[image]

Comment: I get a `list index out of range` on the print statement. I tried printing doc.tables and it was an empty list. I'm sure I have a table in my document

Comment: Could you upload your document?

Comment: upload my word document to stack?